# How to Overwrite Text Color of Tab Component in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Just wanted to know how I can overwrite the Tab Component's color in Material UI?

```
<Tabs className={classes.tabs} inkBarStyle={{ background: 'white' }}>
            <Tab className={classes.tab} label="Home" />
            <Tab className={classes.tab} label="Build" />
            <Tab className={classes.tab} label="Launch" />
            <Tab className={classes.tab} label="About" />
            <Tab className={classes.tab} label="Contact" />
          </Tabs>
```

Comment: if you are using v4, inkBarStyle is not supported anymore. Check documentation

Comment: The documentation for MUI is poor. It is how I ended up here. It should be so complicated to change text color of a component.

Answer (score 0):

I think " !important " can be used for this. For ex in css file:

Tab {
color: **yourcolor** !important
}

sth like

Answer (score 0):

In v4, You need to use `TabIndicatorProps` [Documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/)

```
 <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} 
     className={classes.tabsWrapper}
     TabIndicatorProps={{style: {background:'white'}}}
       <Tab label="TEST1" value={0} />
       <Tab label="TEST2" value={1} />
       <Tab label="TEST3" value={2} />
       <Tab label="TEST4" value={3} />
 </Tabs>
```

Comment: what version of material ui you are using?

Answer (score 0):

So, i apologize. All your solutions did work, but I was stupid not to check that the opacity was set to 0.7, which was causing my problem. I apologize.